# Is this noexcept declaration valid?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

```
struct X
{
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(g()));
    void g() noexcept;
};
```

In vc++ and clang, this works, but gcc is complaining:

```
source_file.cpp:6:34: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
     void f() noexcept(noexcept(g()));
                                  ^
```

I'm thinking that this is a bug in gcc and not a feature in the others. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assessment is [correct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#6)

> Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, noexcept-specifiers, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

In the scope of a complete type, `g` should be found by [unqualified name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#8).